# Functional modeling of API wrapper in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm attempting to learn F# and functional programming and am uncertain how to model the following scenario.

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper around an XML API in F#. This API requires me to first make a "log in" API call with a username and password. The API then returns a session token that is used to authenticate subsequent calls. At some point the session will expire and I will need to "log in" again.

In an object-oriented project I'd create an ApiClient class. It would take the username and password as constructor arguments, expose a public method for each API call and handle the log in process internally. The session token and status could be fully hidden from the consuming application and the session token would be maintained as long as the ApiClient instance lived.

I'm not sure how to organize my code in a functional manner that would achieve a similar result. If I'm not creating an ApiClient class, where do I store the internal session token data? Obviously I could create an ApiClient class in F#, but I'm looking for insight into how to do this more functionally.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Maybe a [free monad](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/242795/what-is-the-free-monad-interpreter-pattern) with an IO evaluator function that takes care of the session stuff?

Comment: This sounds like a close match with this article: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heavily modified my answer to try and condense this process down to the barest essentials to get you started.

The first thing to do is design a system to handle your session state.  The simplest thing to do is to make a type to contain your session data that can only be created inside your library and a second type (which is a discriminated union) to handle validation of that.

```
type SessionData internal (id : System.Guid, creationTime : System.DateTime) = 
    member this.UniqueID  = id
    member this.CreationTime = creationTime

type SessionState<'a> =
    |Valid of 'a * SessionData
    |Invalid
```

Your login function takes a username and password and returns either a valid or invalid session state.

```
let login username password =
    match isUsernameAndPasswordCorrect with
    |true -> Valid ((), SessionData(System.Guid.NewGuid(), System.DateTime.UtcNow))
    |false -> Invalid
```

When we call the API, we are going to update the session state mapping from an old session state to a new one, checking the validity in the process.

```
let private updateSession result (sessionState : SessionData) =
    let loginTimeSpan = sessionState.CreationTime - System.DateTime.UtcNow
    match loginTimeSpan < maxLoginSpan with
    |true -> Valid <| (result, SessionData(System.Guid.NewGuid(), System.DateTime.UtcNow))
    |false -> Invalid
```

Obviously we can make the validation and update process significantly more rigorous if we wish.

Here we are containing the result of a call to your API inside the session state.  Each API Call has:

```
let apiCall args sessionState =
    updateSession (internalFunction args) sessionState
```

If the call is a success, we get a new valid state containing a new session and the result.

---

If you want to hide the process of exchanging session state information entirely, you can create a computation expression to handle that.  A very simple example could be:

```
 type XMLAPIBuilder() =
     member this.Bind (x, f) =
        fun sessionState ->
             match x sessionState with
             |Valid (call, newSessionState) -> f call newSessionState
             |Invalid -> Invalid

     member this.Return(x) =
         fun sessionState -> Valid (x, sessionState)
```

You can use then use this using the computation expression syntax:

```
let xmlapi = XMLAPIBuilder()
let apiCalls = 
    xmlapi {
       let! a = apiCall1 args1
       let! b = apiCall2 args2
       let! c = apiCall3 args3
       return (a, b, c) // result of several api calls
    }
let result = apiCalls session // pass in session data once to retrieve results
```

To entirely remove the session data entirely we could make a new type that doesn't contain the session state and a `run` function:

```
type APICallState<'a> =
    |CallSuccess of 'a
    |CallFailed

let run username password apiExpression =
    match testmagic.login "" "" with
    |Valid (_, state) -> 
        match apiExpression state with
        |Valid (result, _) -> CallSuccess result
        |Invalid -> CallFailed
    |Invalid -> CallFailed
```

This allows us design a complicated expression that makes a series of related calls to your API.  We supply the username and password once, then make all of our calls.

Computation expressions can definitely be one of the less accessible parts of the language to newcomers so I would suggest checking out some tutorials, for example: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html

Comment: Thanks for the thorough write-up. I'm working on it.